# Google Clould Messaging (iOS) put files in default app Documents folder

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to turn on `UIFileSharingEnabled` to let users of my app save some files in their pc.
The problem is that a Google library is putting files inside the main Documents folder of my app without letting me specify a different destination.

This way, if I turn on `UIFileSharingEnabled`, this is what the user can see and interact with (download or delete!)

[image: Files inside app Documents folder]

The 3 folders are mine, so I can move them out easily, but the 3 `.plist` files are a problem. I cannot move them without breaking google functionalities.

I use Cocoapods for loading them inside my project.

```
pod 'Google/Analytics', '1.0.7'
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging', '1.0.7'
```

Any idea on how to fix this? I'm stuck in this situation.
Thanks

Comment: From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW20), it states that the `Apps must put any files they want to share with the user in their <Application_Home>/Documents directory, where <Application_Home> is the path to the app’s home directory.` The `Application_Home` is where your app archive located, but your plist file should put within your XCode development directory, usually same level as your .h and .m file (or .swift file).

Comment: That's the point. It's not my code that creates and save those plist file in the app home directory. Those files should not be shares with the user! At least those should be invisible (by putting a dot in front of their name) if not moved elsewhere

Comment: Oh, i am able to see the plist files in the `<Applicaiton_Home>/Documents` directory too. I think you can report this issue to https://github.com/google/gcm/issues

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: This issue is finally fixed in Firebase version 3.4 from 1 Aug 2016: *"plist files used by FIRMessaging are now stored in an ApplicationSupport directory."* ([source](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios))

Six months later I have the same problem. It turned out GCM developers have failed to fix this bug. I opened another issue ([here](https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/192)) and they confirmed this is not fixed yet. In the meantime Google have announced Firebase Cloud Messaging will inherit GCM. I removed GCM form my app and integrated Firebase. However the issue is still reproducible. These four files are created upon app launch:

- com.google.iid-keypair.plist
- com.google.iid-tokens.plist
- g-checkin.plist
- rmq2.sqlite

I've logged a bug request to Firebase support. I'll update my answer when I see this issue fixed.

Till then I do not recommend to use Firebase Messaging in an iOS application. Your app may be rejected from the App Store for writing temp files to Documents directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, I reported the issue on github.
https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/120

Yesterday a Google guy said it will be fixed in the next version! Yeah!

Comment: I have the same problem. Which version did they fix that?